# Length of binary data in python

Tags: python, byte, python-2.x

I am using Python. I am trying to determine the correct length of bytes in a binary set of data.

If I assign a variable the binary data...

```
x = "aabb".decode("hex")
```

is that the same as

```
x = b'aabb'
```

And if so, how do you get how many bytes that is? (It should be 2 bytes)

When I try:

```
len(x)
```

I get 4 instead of 2 though...

I am worried that x is turned into a string or something else I don't understand because the data types are so fluid in Python...

Comment: When I do `x = "aabb".decode("hex")`, then `len(x)` returns `2`. Is that not what it returns on your machine?

Comment: `"aabb".decode("hex") == b'aabb'` returns False. Your assumption on these two forms being equal is wrong.

Comment: Kevin, you are correct, It is only when I do x = b'aabb' do I get the length of 4, so the question is I guess what does b'aabb' actually do?

Comment: In Python 2, `b'aabb'` is identical to `'aabb'`, but they're different in Python 3. Also, `"aabb".decode("hex")` in Python 3 raises `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`. And `b"aabb".decode("hex")` in Python 3 raises `LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.decode() to handle arbitrary codecs`

Comment: To convert `'aabb'` to the bytestring `b'\xaa\xbb'` in a way that works in both versions you can do: `import binascii;binascii.unhexlify("aabb")`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**The length of binary data is just the `len`**, and the type is `str` in Python-2.x (or `bytes` in Python-3.x). However, your object `'aabb'` does not contain the two bytes 0xaa and 0xbb, rather it contains 4 bytes corresponding with ASCII 'a' and 'b' characters:

```
>>> bytearray([0x61, 0x61, 0x62, 0x62])
bytearray(b'aabb')
>>> bytearray([0x61, 0x61, 0x62, 0x62]) == 'aabb'
True
```

This is probably the equivalence you were *actually* looking for:

```
>>> 'aabb'.decode('hex') == b'\xaa\xbb' 
True
```

The following items are all equal (and length `2`):

```
>>> s1 = 'aabb'.decode('hex')
>>> s2 = b'\xaa\xbb'
>>> s3 = bytearray([0xaa, 0xbb])
>>> s4 = bytearray([170, 187])
>>> s1 == s2 == s3 == s4
True
```

Comment: hmm.. would be good to answer the title though rather than the body text

Comment: @ElliotWoods  I've edited to put it first and foremost.