# How to find length of list in byte format?

Tags: python, list, byte

I have a data variable which contains a `list` of `dicts` of `lists` that i have fetched from an api, formatted as `bytes`. The list is variable in length.

```
In: data
Out: b'[{"dict1_list1":[1,2,3],"dict1_list2":[4,5,6]},{"dict2_list1":[1,2,3],"dict2_list2":[4,5,6]}]'
```

I want to identify when there is only one dict in the list (i.e. the api has run out of data)

```
In: data
Out: b'[{"onlydict_list1":[1,2,3],"onlydict_list2":[4,5,6]}]'
```

but because data is formatted as `byte` I cannot return the length of the list.

```
In: len(data)
Out: 53  # Not '1' as I would like
```

How can I identify the length of the list within the `b'[....]'`?

Comment: That is not a `list` in "bytes format", that is a `bytes` object. This looks like your API is returning a JSON, why are you not decoding this JSON?

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726217/length-of-binary-data-in-python

Comment: OK, thanks. Yes it is JSON that I am reading into a pandas `dataframe` `df= pd.read_json(data)` but it is creating a pandas exception when there is only one list, so I want to identify that case and trap it.

Comment: @doctorer then the straight-forward way is to use *exception handling*.

Comment: @doctorer can you provide an example of a `bytes` object that is causing your `pd.read_json` to error out?

Comment: I think you're right @ juanpa.arrivillaga that exception handling is the way to go.I was asking the wrong question, so may delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If r is response then try calling r.json() method . It will convert to a list and then you can find the length of it . You can also use json.loads(r.text) by importing json(import json).

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the length of the bytes object, which is apparently the type of `data`, **not** a Python version of the JSON object to which it corresponds.

A simple way to do it would be to first convert the data into the Python object equivalent of the byte-string using `json.loads()`. Here's what I mean:

```
import json

data = (b'[{"dict1_list1":[1,2,3],"dict1_list2":[4,5,6]},'
         b'{"dict2_list1":[1,2,3],"dict2_list2":[4,5,6]}]')

print(len(json.loads(data)))  # -> 2
```